# How to *only* change x coordinate with Vector3.MoveTowards while snapping y coordinate to a curve?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So in the back of my mind I'm sure there's a way to do this but I can't seem to figure it out.  It's such a specific question I'm having a difficult time finding an answer in my internet searches.

I have an object that I want to smoothly follow my mouse, not snap to it, so I'm using Vector3.movetowards as so:

```
void Update () {

    mousePos = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, camera.nearClipPlane));

    targetPos = new Vector3(mousePos.x, GetHeight(mousePos.x), PaddlePosition.z);

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, moveSpeed);

}

private float GetHeight(float xCoordinate){

    float height = Mathf.Abs(xCoordinate) * heightDeviation + PaddlePosition.y;
    return height;
}
```

Basically when it goes right or left it goes slightly upwards based on how far away from 0 the mouse's x coordinate is.  That part works.

The problem is if the mouse is moved rapidly from one side to the other, because of the nature of how vector3.movetowards works, I end up with the object following a different path on the y-axis than intended.  I would like to retain the smooth, slightly delayed following motion I'm getting on the x axis but always have the y-axis locked to the coordinate generated by GetHeight().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe can be done with more control, and less code, via the [**constraints**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Constraints.html) features of Unity.

The [**position constraint**](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PositionConstraint.html)'s properties can all be animated, both from code and animation timelines, giving you incredible creative powers for minimal effort.

Constrain your object to the mouse pointer via an empty object at the mouse pointer, and animate and/or set distance and relative properties in the constraint as desired.

Comment: I looked into using this as you suggested.  I suppose I could constrain it to follow the mouse with the empty object and then dynamically update y based on the transform's x location but then I lose the aforementioned smooth, delayed "following" I got using Vector3.MoveTowards.  Is there a way to get that form of motion using the constraints?

Comment: Yes, you adjust the distance of the constraint based on whatever smoothness you want. Could be based on the speed of the mouse and an amount of distance to the object and factored by time, or any other combination of contributing factors you like.

Comment: @Ace the best gradient I've found for these things is to use an ease curve, of the exponential type, through one of the tween libraries. DOTween has a free version, and here's another that's pretty cool: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/leantween-3595

Comment: So I figured out a fairly simple way to do this thanks to your advice!  I have the object following a MouseFollower object's x-axis only and updating it's own y-axis by way of it's own x coordinate.  I simply used the same Vector3.moveTowards script I had on the object on the MouseFollower and that gave me the smooth motion in the x-axis I sought but retained the y-coordinates regardless of the speed the mouse moved.  Thanks for your help!